# Server Load Impact fo Parsing XML Files using PHP

Tags: php, xml

What effect will the server load have if there are a lot of items that are getting parsed in an XML file via PHP, say 1 million items and what is the difference between parsing 10 items and 1million items. Is there a solution to cache the html generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between parsing 10 and 1 million is easy - 100,000 times.

The impact depends on the size of the files, how you're loading them, how you're parsing them, etc.

You can easily time how long it takes to execute a script:

```
$start = time();
//...your script
echo "Time taken: ".(time()-$start)." seconds";
```

Run your script with, say, 100 files. If it takes 5 seconds, you can assume it'll take roughly 50,000 seconds to run with a million files.

Really need more detail to be able to answer with any more certainty.

Comment: Thank you for that. Actually, my entire website runs with data stored in xml files. I am parsing them using PHP and outputting the HTML generated on another php page. I am looking for a way to cache the html pages so that it decreases the load.

Comment: Just create a million HTML files might be the easiest?

Comment: Well, that suggests there is no caching solution.. :(

Comment: That is a form of caching! You currently have a million XML files - you're currently having to parse/process them, then create some HTML to display it. Creating a million HTML files cuts out the parsing/processing phase, and means you can deliver the files directly and a lot more quickly, so IS a cache.